# Pivot table Run Time error 1004: Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code which basically gets pivot tables row field and tries to update link associated with those row entries.

#### Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'this exist
Set PvtTbl = PivotTables("pt1")

'this exist    
Set pvtFields = PvtTbl.RowFields(1)
   

For Each cel In pvtFields.DataRange
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column), Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column)), Address:="https://www.google.com/"
    Next cel
        
End Sub
```

#### Problem

Whenever I run this code, it errors out with "Run Time error 1004: Application-defined or object defined error"

#### Note

1. Excel has unrestricted access
2. Debugged that `Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column)` always produce value
3. Debugged that `Range(Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column), Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column))` always produce value
4. I get same error when I replaced cel.Row  and cel.column with valid values (e.g 7,3). But, it works on same sheet (e.g. row,col: 1,1 which doesn't have pivot table.)
5. I tried Worksheet_SelectionChange and Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate events but nothing helped.

Not sure, what's really missing here in the pivot table. Please let me know if you see something.

Thanks

Comment: Does "pt1" exist?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert hyperlinks inside the pivot table.

If you try to do it manually, you will see that when the cell inside the Pivot is selected, the **Insert link** menu also gets disabled.

[image]

And when you click outside the pivot, it gets enabled.

[image]

Here is another way to achieve what you want

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
        Set PvtTbl = PivotTables(1)
        
        Dim pvtFields As PivotField
        Set pvtFields = PvtTbl.RowFields(1)

        If Not Intersect(Target, pvtFields.DataRange) Is Nothing Then
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://www.google.com/"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```